# JS Not firing on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to load the function `call_ajax_add_to_quotelist` via the button with the following code:

`$cartlink .= '<a class="add_to_cart button alt" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url,'.$product->id.');" '.$style.'>'.$label.'</a>';`

The code above is loading fine on the view source however when clicked it is showing dead with no console error I have loaded the `js` file in the function (It belongs to another plugin I am hacking a WP plugin with the same actions of another plugin)

**Script Load:**

```
$quotePluginJSUrl = site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/dvin-wcql/js/dvin_wcql.js';
?>
        <script src="<?php echo $quotePluginJSUrl; ?>"></script>
<?php
```

Comment: Try making it call this, to see if it is a clicking or a function problem.
    console.log("clicked!");

Comment: You didn't close the anchor

Comment: I assumed that we were missing code.

Comment: Now that you closed the anchor and still doesn't work.
Please post the `call_ajax_add_to_quotelist` function

Comment: Silly question, but did you activate the plugin ?

Comment: @Sekai Yes its activated im dealing with two plugins here as I am trying to cover some areas that one plugin didnt provide but the other did etc - They both work how they should just need to get the missing URI working

Comment: Make sure that one's functions don't override the other's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would a t first check, if `call_ajax_add_to_quotelist` is really a function in JavaScript Console, and if `add_to_quotelist_ajax_url` is a correct value.

Also, it is recommended to *not* use `onclick`. I recommend using jQuery event binder [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Expl.:

```
<?php
$cartlink .= "<a class='add_to_cart button' data-id='{$product->id}' 
   href='javascript:;' {$style}>{$label}</a>";
// ... more products
?>
```

---

```
// **one** <script> after all products
<script>
jQuery(window).on('click', '.add_to_cart.button', function() {
    call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url, $(this).data('id');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Fully agree with the use of `data-`.

Comment: Thanks,  How ever your script is giving me a couple of unexpected token ; errors

Comment: @Debflav I am sorry but im still confused as to what it should be

Comment: @JessMcKenzie I changed my code a bit. Maybe your errors are gone now. Also, did you make the check I wrote about first?

Comment: @HerrSerker Its not showing an edit and yes I did and its  function :)

Answer (score 1):

Close the anchor

```
<a>...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are adding the anchor dynamically, you need to use `.addEventListener` if you're using JS or Event Delegation if you're using jQuery

e.g.

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url,'.$product->id.');
});
```

Plus you haven't closed the anchor tag in your code which might cause you some problems:

```
$cartlink .= '<a class="add_to_cart button alt" href="javascript:void(0);" '.$style.'>'.$label.'</a>'
```

Comment: +1 for explanation but`'.$product->id.'` is supposed to be PHP code. It would not work.